# JQuery: I'm trying to create one input and the event returns multiple ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm fairly new to Javascript and Jquery. My current project is a very simple tasklist. My html has an input, a button and an ul. I created an function on js that creates a li item inside the ul everytime the user writes something on the input and clicks on the button. Said li, includes an edit button.
What I'm trying to do now is: make an event so, when the "edit" button is clicked, an input is created on which I can rewrite my message. Right now, the problem I'm having is that I'm stuck on trying to create the input. I'm trying to use the following code:

```
function Edit() {
    $('.edit').on('click', function() { 
    //this line assigns an event on buttons with class:"edit"
    var data = $(this).attr("data-id") 
    //this var returns the data-id value of the specific button I pressed       
    var container = $("#d"+data) 
    //this brings me the div that contains, among other things, the "edit" button.
    var input = '<input type="text">'; 
    //creates an input
    container.append(input) 
    //apends the input to the div` 
  });
}
```

My problem right now is: this works if I have just one element created on my tasklist, if I have more than one, it creates as many inputs as elements are on the  ul at that time for the first one, and then starts substracting one on the subsequent ones.
I have been thinking about this for hours, and I can't seem to grasp the reason why this happens, so I'd really appreciate some input so I can understand what's going on and solve it.
Thanks a lot!!!

Edited to add the html:
my html is the following

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Mi lista de tareas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Mi lista de tareas</h1>
        <div id="ingreso">
            <div id="input-boton">
                <input type="text" id="inputId"/>
                <button id="agregar">Agregar</button>
            </div>
            <ul id="lista">
            </ul>
        </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/toDoList.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The "agregar" button creates a node like this:

```
`<div id=(assigned by a counter)>
   <li>
    <div>
      <edit button>
      <delete button>
    </div>
  </li>
</div`
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to provide your HTML also, to check what's happening

Comment: Thanks!!! I added the html to the original message. Have a great day!!!

Comment: When is the `Edit` function called?

Comment: when I press a .Edit button, which generates everytime an item is added to the list